# copy images from one server to another in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, copy

i have a web app in PHP on one server (ubuntu1), and i have a script to upload a image to one directory in the same server.

the problem is now we are moving the images to another server (ubuntu2).

what is the best way to move the images to the new server?

i was thinking, after the upload is complete use exec and scp to copy the image, for that i need to define one use in every server (ssh-keygen, pub key and authorized_keys files).

but

- the user on ubuntu1 is www-data, and i think is not a good idea set up this user for ssh.
- if i use "su user -c 'scp ....'", what about when the script ask for the password?
- or another idea to do this?

the copy is over internet.

Comment: Do you have to do this in PHP? If you have shell access, you can use SCP or RSYNC.

Comment: I have access, but i want it to be right after the user upload an image.

Comment: if you're going to allow a script to do `su`, you might as well just set it up to do scp in the first place. you've gained absolutely NO security and any intruders who gain www-data rights would now also get access to this account you're `su`-ing to.

Comment: In which case, I would be inclined to either POST the image to the second server, with a PHP script to handle it, or call a URL on the second server that then fetches the image from a URL on the first server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to your server, you could use the [php_ssh2](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)-Modul, which comes with a [scp-Method](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ssh2-scp-send.php). This way, you do not have to think that much about suing and other shell-related security issues.

But maybe you could copy the file via cron later to the other server, so the user does not have to wait, until this job is done.